# Use of would in first conditionals

Tags: conditionals, will-would, irrealis-mood

> If it's someone whose death you don't even have to know about, you still wouldn't push the button?

In a sentence of first conditionals, dependant clause is constructed in simple present (1st form of verb) tense and independent clause is constructed in simple future (will/shall + bare infinitive). The above mentioned example has **would** in the independent clause while it is a first type of conditionals. So, can we use would in first type of conditionals?

Comment: This sentence is written informally. If written formally, it would read: "*If it **were** someone else's death you **didn't** even have to know about...*". Does that answer your question?

Comment: @gotube If such mismatchings are not always possible in informal language, a generalization is still called for.

Comment: @Apollyon It's outside the scope of this site to provide verifiable answers about informal speech. Saying something is ungrammatical, but acceptable in informal speech is about as far as we can go. There are no authoritative sources on rules of informal English as they're only studied very locally by sociolinguists. I think this question is unlikely to get any answers, but I'd like to hear back from the OP first